# Jface TreeSelection / StructuredSelection sort order

Tags: treeview, swt, jface, nebula

I am using the Eclipse Nebula `GridTreeViewer` which lets me access the selected items via a `TreeSelection`.

This works all good except for the sort order of the elements which are returned via `StructuredSelection#iterator()`. The sort order considers the order in which the elements were actually selected (e.g. when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button for multi selection).

What I would need is the top=>down order of the elements as they are shown on the GUI.

I tried sorting the selection and then re-selecting with the new order. But unfortunately, the selection seems to be only updated if the actually selected elements change.

Does anyone know any other way to do this?

Comment: JFace/SWT doesn't have a `GridTreeViewer`. What is the full package name of this class? Is it Eclipse Nebula class or Eclipse RAP or ...?

Comment: Sorry, thats true. It is org.eclipse.nebula.jface.gridviewer.GridTreeViewer